# Permanently unmap network printer (from network locations)

Tags: connection, network-drive

I have a printer that creates an unusable 'network drive' in the computer, and thus reserves that drive letter.  I have a lot of hard disks and need every drive letter available.  It is annoying to disconnect the drive each time I log in.  How can I stop the printer from creating this network drive without a net-use-bat-file?

The network drive isn't listening in disk management so I can't simply remove the drive letter.

Here is a guy with a similar [**question**](http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/windows-vista/473176-printer-mapped-drive.html).

I'm using windows 7 Ultimate x64 and the printer is a HP Officejet 7310 AIO.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the printer to your network, use a browser pointed to it's IP address to log in (You can get that by having it print a configuration page, see it's manual).
There may be a setting to get it to stop claiming a drive letter.

I'd start there.

Comment: Tried that, but there isn't really any settings in the web frontend, only language. :(